# Historical data for 3 month and 6 month lows for NYSE or Nasdaq

Tags: historical-data, nyse

I'm trying to find the historical data for 3 month or 6 month lows.

Thinkorswim has it (NYLO3M) and barcharts.com has it (M3LN) but they don't match...and thinkorswim only goes back to 2012.

Does anyone know of another source where I could get this data?

Comment: Are you looking just for the number of stocks making new lows, or also the names of these stocks?

Comment: Just the number of stocks that are making new 3 month lows (and/or 6 month lows).  I've been able to easily find 12 month lows...but not for the other intervals @noob2

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to :

1. Visit : [yahoo finance Nasdaq page](https://fr.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EIXIC/history?p=%5EIXIC)
2. Click on "Historical Data"
3. Enter your date range
4. Click on "download"
5. You get a .csv file with all your data (including the lows)
6. If you do not know how to clean a csv file, I suggest you click on the first column which includes your data, then "Data" ribbon, then "Text To column" and you're there !

I hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks, but this won't help with finding the number of stocks that make 3 month new lows.  This just downloads stock prices.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but once you have daily data, it should not be too difficult to do it without a datasource? 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.min.html pulls the lowest value within any rolling window - you could filter for current value and if it matches, you know it is low in that period. 
or something like '''x = np.random.random(50)    
df = pd.DataFrame({'random': x})     

minimum = df['random'].rolling(window = 4).min() == df['random']    
mins = df[minimum]''' as a dummy example in Python

Comment: Note to anyone doing this with yahoo finance - this will cause survivorship bias because yahoo finance doesn't track delisted stocks.